# MySQL ODBC Driver - Is there a way to block an access of MySQL Connector ODBC Driver?

Tags: mysql, odbc

Good afternoon, i have 2 PC's, where one is my WAMP server, with MySQL Database and so on. And the other i made a connection to my DB throw MySQL Connector ODBC Driver.

My doubt is if is there a way to block access of this second PC to my Server PC ?

I'm learning about MySQL control management, and i came across with this case, and i couldn't found an answer searching about this by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no builtin mechanism in MySQL Server that detects that a connection attempt is from a MySQL Connector ODBC Driver, and blocks the connection.

It is possible to block connections to the MySQL Server, by setting up the appropriate user definitions in MySQL Server (entries in the `mysql.user` table).

In MySQL, a user is identified by a *user* name together with a *host* (either a DNS hostname or IP address, depending on whether we've specified `skip-name-resolve` option.)

If we setup MySQL users with wildcard hostname '%', then we are allowing TCP/IP connections from any host or any IP address.

If we remove user entries with a wildcard hostname, and instead create users with a more specific hostname (or IP address), then connections will be allowed only from the specified host/IP address. With a net effect of blocking connections from other hosts.

This topic is more fully addressed in the MySQL Reference Manual

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-access.html

---

Also, for TCP/IP connection attempts, a network firewall (for example, Iptables on Linux) can be configured to knock down connections before they are even seen by MySQL Server.

Comment: I see. I'll try do something like you said, thank you very much !!